# Position absolute after center under div

Tags: html, css, css-position, center, absolute

i have problem with after position absolute. I can't centering content after div. My code:[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/MHDDD/88/)

I checked other post but unfortunately they did not help me.

```css
.nav {
  height: 20px;
}
.w {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 20px;
}
.e:after {
  content: "W";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 350px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="q">
    <li class="w">
      <a href="" class="e">Testttttt</a>
    </li>

    <li class="w">
      <a href="" class="e">Testtttttttttt</a>
    </li>

    <li class="w">
      <a href="" class="e">Testttttttttttttttt</a>
    </li>

    <li class="w">
      <a href="" class="e">Test</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: what you want to do exactly?? It is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are tying to center the :after pseudo element. You can't center an element with `text-align:center` after you assign `position:absolute` to it. You have to use left,right position along with negative margin. Try this code.

```
.e{
  position: relative;
}
.e:after {
  content: "W";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 0;
  bottom: -50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Yea, this is my solution. Thank You for help :)!

Comment: Happy to help, keep coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `text-align: center;` to nav class in css

```css
.nav {
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.w {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 20px;
}

.e:after {
  content: "W";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 350px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="q">
    <li class="w">
      <a href="" class="e">Testttttt</a>
    </li>

    <li class="w">
      <a href="" class="e">Testtttttttttt</a>
    </li>

    <li class="w">
      <a href="" class="e">Testttttttttttttttt</a>
    </li>

    <li class="w">
      <a href="" class="e">Test</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```